# Sum involving zeta functions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, zeta-functions

Find closed form of the following -

$$ \displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{(n-1)\zeta(n)}{4n-1}\right)} $$

I don't know how to approach to it - Using the integral definition? I cannot use because I came to this result from there only.

Comment: As written, the series is trivially diverging. Maybe you want to replace $\zeta(n)$ with $\left(\zeta(n)-1\right)$.

Comment: Okay then replace $ \zeta(n) \rightarrow (\zeta(n) -1) $ and then find the answer. It might be that I read the problem wrongly. @JackD'Aurizio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One may observe that
$$
\zeta(n)=1+\frac1{2^n}+\frac1{3^n}+\cdots,\quad n>1,
$$
gives
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\zeta(n)=1,
$$ then

> $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty}{\left(\frac{(n-1)\zeta(n)}{4n-1}\right)}=\frac14 \times 1\neq0.
> $$

Your series, as written, is **divergent**.

Comment: Oh, I see. Should this also diverge - $$ \displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{(n-1)\zeta(n)}{4n-1} - 1\right)} $$ ?

Comment: Actually I was working on the following summation $$\sum _{ s=1 }^{ \infty }{ \left( \frac { 1 }{ 4s-1 } \sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty }{ \left( \frac { 1 }{ n+1 } \sum _{ k=0 }^{ n }{ \left( \left( \begin{matrix} n \\ k \end{matrix} \right) \frac { { \left( -1 \right) }^{ k } }{ { \left( k+1 \right) }^{ s-1 } } \right) } \right) } -1 \right) }$$ and I am getting the sum as written above. It's my bad that I changed the problem. @Olivier Oloa

Comment: @KartikSharma Did you mean to write $\left(\dotsb-\dfrac14\right)$? He said that the limit was $\frac14$, so I'd expect you to subtract $\frac14$ to make the limit $0$.

Comment: I'd expect to do as you said. But then that is not what I get from the original problem as stated above. Check out, please!

Answer (score 1):

If you replace $\zeta(n)$ with $\zeta(n)-1$ (otherwise the series is trivially diverging, as shown by the other answers), since $\sum_{n\geq 2}\left(\zeta(n)-1\right)=1$ we just need to compute:
$$ S = \sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{\zeta(n)-1}{4n-1}. \tag{1}$$
On the other hand,
$$ \sum_{n\geq 2}\zeta(n)\, z^n = -z\left(\gamma+\psi(1-z)\right)\tag{2}$$
hence by replacing $z$ with $z^4$, then dividing by $z^2$:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 2}\zeta(n)\,z^{4n-2} = -z^2(\gamma+\psi(1-z^4))\tag{3}$$
so:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 2}\left(\zeta(n)-1\right)\,z^{4n-2} = -\gamma z^2-z^2\psi(1-z^4)-\frac{z^6}{1-z^4}\tag{4}$$
and:
$$ S = -\frac{\gamma+1}{3}-\int_{0}^{1}x^2\,\psi(2-x^4)\,dx \tag{5}$$
but honestly I do not think the last integral has a nice closed form.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{\zeta\left(n\right)\left(n-1\right)}{4n-1}\geq\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{\zeta\left(n\right)}{n}\geq\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{1}{n}.
 $$